# Why use a Java Interface for just one class?

Tags: java, interface, software-design

I was reading someone's code recently, and they'd created an interface which was only implemented by one class. It seemed to me like the interface was unnecessary. What design reasons are there for creating an interface that is only implemented by one class?

Comment: because codes can be improved, if later in the future another class that needs the interface is written, this will make it a lot easier to do.

Comment: @Olayinka, why put that as a comment instead of as an answer?

Comment: @SimonT Too short I guess. I'll remember to post as answer next time.

Comment: why you need a blueprint if you can directly create a tall building?

Comment: @maxx777, a class is kind of like a blueprint already :P  An interface is like a blueprint blueprint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. Testing. Classes that implement interfaces can easily be replaced by stubs, mocks, wrappers, etc during automated testing.
2. Future expansion. Just because there's only one implementation now doesn't mean more aren't planned or imagined.

Comment: I hadn't considered the testing aspect. Especially since the future expansion thing doesn't make as much sense to me in this case, considering that the interface is named Manager, and the class is name ManagerImpl ... it was pretty specifically created for this interface. Not that they still couldn't add more classes that implement it.

Comment: Thanks to #2 I've been able to replace a rss-based implementation with a json-based one in few hours. #1 helped to make sure I didn't break anything.

Answer (score 1):

He/she may simply be trying to define a role that other classes can play, especially if more classes are added later on. Say you have a Pet interface. You might have a Dog and RoboDog class that both implement that interface later even though they possibly come from different inheritance trees.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, right now you are not required it but in future if you need to change the implementation or want to add a new behavior then it's impossible to manage the changes.

> Changes is the biggest factor of IT industry. Developer spend more time on maintenance rather than development.

**You don't want to change the implementation of existing class because its tested for last many years**. If you change it then it will create a huge impact on the related classes also and you have to test your complete application from the beginning. It adds regression issues.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  It's not that the interface can only be implemented once, it's that the programmer only made one class that implements the interface.